# How come there's no ValueMap?

Tags: associations

There's a `KeyMap`, but there's no `ValueMap`.  How come?

By `ValueMap` I mean a function that takes as arguments a function $f$ and an association $\text{<|} key_1 \to value_1, key_2 \to value_2, \cdots \text{|>}$, and produces the association $\text{<|} key_1 \to f(value_1), key_2 \to f(value_2), \cdots \text{|>}$.

Of course, I realize that one can approximate such a function using pre-existing functions , but same could be said of `KeyMap`.

The absence of a `ValueMap` makes me wonder if I'm misundertanding something.  IOW, maybe wanting something like `ValueMap` is a sign that one is not thinking about the problem in the right way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Map >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Map[f, <|"a" -> 1, a -> 2, 1 -> 1|>]
```

> <|"a" -> f[1], a -> f[2], 1 -> f[1]|>